# C# NullReferenceException on ASSIGNMENT after Set Next Statement

Tags: c#, debugging, nullreferenceexception

When using Set Next Statement while debugging, i.e. skipping certain statements, sometimes a strange thing happens: a `NullReferenceException`is thrown on *assignment* of a variable.

**The problem seems to happen when I have skipped a statement that would have caused an exception to be thrown (and potentially caught elsewhere).** For example, I might have first skipped the construction of an object, and then later have skipped a member access to that object (which would have thrown its own `NullReferenceException`).

Note that there is no member being accessed on a null reference anywhere. What seems to be happening, is that an assignment is being made to a variable whose declaration has been skipped [by some optimization, I guess]. By stepping, I have skipped an exception that was already concluded to be unavoidable, and as such the variable was never expected to be used and has not been declared.

I claim the above because the problem disappears when I either:

1. Outcomment rather than skip over the statements that would throw; or
2. declare the variable at the top of the method.

Is my interpretation correct?

Which process (e.g. the JIT) causes this behavior, and why?

Comment: Care to provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Without the actual exception content it's impossible to answer. Post the *full* extension text, including the call stack. You can get that easily with `Exception.ToString()`. Perhaps a property setter tries to read a null field. Perhaps whatever creates the value tries to read a null value. Perhaps the assignment is forcing the evaulation of an IEnumerable whose creator tries to access a null.

Comment: The only thing that's certain is that if you get an NRE, you're trying to read a `null` value somewhere

Comment: There is cause and affect.  When you have a null object the cause is you didn't get any data and the affect is an exception occurs when you try to read a null object.  So skipping the statement just bypassed the reading of a null object.  The root cause is the null object.  You have to find out why you got the null.

Comment: @RenéVogt I've edit this question to add an example. wait for pass the peer reviewed